# Vehicle Stalls at lights and going up hills

Tags: engine, automatic-transmission

After driving a few miles, 2002 Ford Explorer will start sputtering after stopping at a light. Also, does the same thing when going up hills.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It doesn't appear you've actually asked a question. Could you add any other pertinent detail? What exactly have you done? What have you looked at? Is the check engine light on? If so, have you had the codes read? What is the engine/mileage of the vehicle? Any other information you can give us?

Comment: Any OBD codes? please post them.

Comment: You say "after a few miles." Is this after the engine gets up to operating temperature? Is there any smoke or steam coming from the exhaust (or from under the hood)? Has it *ever* been overheated?

Comment: Stopping creates high vacuum condition while going uphill reduces vacuum level to minimum under load so I wonder if vacuum sensing or controls need calibration or some other vacuum related timing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your car's spark plugs. Make sure the recommended clearance is set and they are not worn out. It's good to clean the fuel injectors.

Comment: This happened to me once, I prefer determined my spark plugs to be pretty gapped and installed them, stopped at the first light and it died, tried to turn the steering wheel and it died, I made it  back home but it was hell lol

Answer (score 0):

The stalling appears to be a function of fuel flow to the engine.  OK at low demand. This suggests that a fuel filter may allow some fuel flow but shuts off flow levels above this.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning, the fuel pressure regulator, hook up a fuel pressure tester on the shrader value and pinch the line before the fuel pressure regulator, pressure should rise on the psi gauge, if it doesn't then check your fuel module fuse in the engine and check the fuel filter, then check for any leaks. Typically it's around 55 I believe with no fluctuating, when starting, if it drops 5 to 7 psi it's probably the filter.